# is the norm of a function invariant of translation?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

While doing exercises I stumbled upon this question: Suppose $(G, +)$ is a group and consider the space $\mathbb{C}^G$ of all complex valued functions acting on $G$. Further assume that $\mathbb{C}^G$ is endowed with a norm $\lVert . \rVert$. Is it true that the norm is invariant of translation, i.e. does it hold that
$$ \lVert f(. + a) \rVert = \lVert f(.) \rVert $$
for all translations $a \in G$?

The question arose from the fact that commonly used norms on function spaces such as suprumumnorms and integralnorms have such a property. However, I could not come up with a norm that does not have this property.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Consider $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},+)$, so that ${\mathbb C}^G  \simeq \mathbb{C}^2$, and consider the norm $\|(z_0,z_1)\|:=|z_0| + 2 |z_1|$.

(Note: the set of functions from $G$ to $\mathbb C$ is denoted by ${\mathbb C}^G$ rather than $G^{\mathbb C}$, which would be the set of $G$-valued functions defined on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: That's smart. Thanks! Are there also counter examples for groups with non-finite order?